# Inserting a character in a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, insert, character

My task is::::
delete all the vowels,
insert a character "." after each consonant.

so the program i made always inserts "." at the begining .........
help me

http://ideone.com/Y8DoXt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
bool isVowel(char ch);

int main()
{
    string orwr;
    int j = 0;
    getline(cin, orwr);
    for (j=0; j<6; j++)
    {
     if(isVowel(orwr[j])==1)
       {orwr.erase(j, 1);j--;}
     else
       {orwr.insert(j, 1, '.');j++;}
    }
cout<<orwr;
return 0;
}


bool isVowel(char ch)
{
    switch(ch)
    {case 'a':
    case 'A':
    case 'e':
    case 'E':
    case 'i':
    case 'I':
    case 'o':
    case 'O':
    case 'u':
    case 'U':
        return true;
    default:
        return false;}}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly to make it readable.

Comment: what else do u need???????????????? @PaulR

Comment: Hints: Say you have `'x'` at `j` = 1. You insert `'.'` at 0. You increment `j` to 2. At which position is the `'x'` after the insertion?

Comment: @GaneshSawhney Remember that `insert` will insert *before* the character at the given index, and that the length of the string isn't necessarily preserved after you've done those operations.

Comment: Some basics of asking good questions: what input did you type, what output did you get, how did that differ from what you expected, what don't you understand about why it differs?

Answer (score 2):

Your loop shoul be :

```
    for (j=0; j<orwr.length(); j++)
```

and not:

```
    for (j=0; j<6; j++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, I would reverse the loop so you do not have to adjust any indizes:

```
for(int j = orwr.length()-1; j >= 0; --j) {
    if(isVowel(orwr[j]))
        orwr.erase(j, 1);
    else
        orwr.insert(j, 1, '.');
}
```